How to define a patchwork math font?
I want to define a math font \cal which is defined for all uppercase and lowercase letters such that \cal{<letter>} is set to \mathcal{<letter>} if <letter> is uppercase, and \bm{<letter>} if <letter> is lowercase.
Actually, since bm is much more flexible in terms of what it can take as an argument (numbers, math symbols, ...) it would be nice if \cal would default to \bm for all of these, only switching to \mathcal for uppercase letters.

Once you see the output of $\mathcal{E}\bm{ff}$ you'll change idea.

if you don't need normal bold italic, easiest would be to modify bm to use the cal font, but it seems a very strange thing to do, since you are anyway using explicit markup why not use \bm and \mathcal

If we suppose that the parameter of \cal is only single letter then we can do the test of uppercase letter by \uppercase{\ifx#1}#1. In your case:
\def\cal#1{\uppercase{\ifx#1}#1\mathcal{#1}\else\bm{#1}\fi}


I don't think you really want \bm:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\ccal}{m}
 {
  \andres_ccal_process:n {#1}
 }

\tl_new:N \l__andres_ccal_input_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \andres_ccal_process:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__andres_ccal_input_tl {#1}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([a-z]+) } { \c{bm}\{\1\} } \l__andres_ccal_input_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([a-z]+) } { \c{betterboldforccal}\{\1\} } \l__andres_ccal_input_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__andres_ccal_input_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\ccal{Eff}$

\end{document}


Slightly less horrible:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\NewDocumentCommand{\betterboldforccal}{m}{%
  \textnormal{\bfseries\itshape #1}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\ccal}{m}
 {
  \andres_ccal_process:n {#1}
 }

\tl_new:N \l__andres_ccal_input_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \andres_ccal_process:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__andres_ccal_input_tl {#1}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([A-Z]+) } { \c{mathcal}\{\1\} } \l__andres_ccal_input_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([a-z]+) } { \c{bm}\{\1\} } \l__andres_ccal_input_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__andres_ccal_input_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\ccal{Eff}$

\end{document}


This only applies to lowercase and uppercase letters. If you need \bm, resist the temptation to apply it to several tokens at once, unless they're just letters.
